# undefined is not a function in canjs

Tags: javascript, ejs, canjs

I am trying to fetch data from the json array using canjs in html file with ejs template engine.

But when I load the html file on browser It shows the error that "Undefined is not a function".

This is my todo.js

```js
var Todo = can.Model({
 findall : 'GET/todos',
 findone : 'GET/todos{id}',
 create  : 'POST/todos',
 update  : 'PUT/todos/{id}',
 remove  : 'DELETE/todos/{id}'

},{})

(function(){
 var TODOS =  [{id: 1,name : 'Dipesh'},
            {id: 2,name : 'John'},
            {id: 3,name : 'Joseph'}];

     can.fixture("DELETE/todos/{id}",function(request){
      return {};
     });
     can.fixture("PUT/todos/{id)", function(request){
      $.extend(TODOS[(+request.data.id)-1], request.data);
      return {};
     });
     can.fixture("POST/todos", function(request){
      var id = TODOS.length + 1;
      TODOS.push($.extend({id:id},request.data));
      return {id:id, name: request.data};
     });
  can.fixture("GET/todos", function(request){
   return TODOS;
  });
  can.fixture("GET/todos/{id}", function(request){
   return TODOS[(+request.data.id)-1];
  });
})();

Todo.findall({}, function(todos){
 var frag = can.view('todosEJS', todos)
 document.getElementById("todos")
    .appendChild(frag);
})
```

This is my html file:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Canjs </title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id = 'todos'></ul>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='../can.custom.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='todos.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<script id = 'todosEJS' type = 'text/ejs'>
 <% for(var i = 0;i<this.length;i++){%>
  <li><%=this[i].name%></li>
 <% } %>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its showing an error at line **Todo.findall({}, function(todos){** as "undefined is not a function".
Anybody have a solution?

Comment: Im getting the same error as well! not sure if i m missing any additional libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

- The static methods on can.Model are findAll and findOne, not findall and findone.
- The fixture URLs should have a space between the HTTP verb and the URL. So 'POST/todos' should be 'POST /todos'.
- The fixture for PUT is missing a matching }. It should be 'PUT /todos/{id}'

Here's your example working on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/waqihidajo/1/edit

Comment: It gives me whole loop logic. like <% for(var i = 0;i
<%= this[i].name %>
<% } %> Even I copied your code.

Comment: EJS is not included with core CanJS. It's a plugin you have to include. So either include can.ejs.js or use the download builder on canjs.com to build a custom bundle.Mustache is the default templating engine in CanJS.

Answer (score 1):

Methods are `findAll` and `findOne`. Try this:

```
var Todo = can.Model({
    findAll : 'GET /todos',
    findOne : 'GET /todos{id}',
    create  : 'POST /todos',
    update  : 'PUT /todos/{id}',
    remove  : 'DELETE /todos/{id}'
}, {});
```

Comment: Make sure you replace all `findall` occurrences to `findAll`. Put a space between HTTP method and URL like `POST /todos`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Include can.ejs.js and the error will be resolved.
Download can.ejs.js from  [here](https://canjs.com/download.html)